# Laravel forge custom vps

Tags: php, laravel, forge

I've got a vps with a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04 x64. I would like to use this for `Laravel Forge`. [image]

But what software do I have to install now?

Forge is giving me this:

Almost there! Here is your server's provision command. You should SSH into your server as root and run the command in your terminal. This command will begin the provisioning process for your server, and will configure the server so that it can be managed by Forge.

```
wget -O forge.sh https://forge.laravel.com/servers/1008/vps?forge_token=Byix7lMfGiMTWh9KasdfjioafhewalkJeAHY; bash forge.sh
OK
```

(modified the token)

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with Forge, but I don't think you want to share your token around.

Answer (score 2):

You have to ssh to your server and run that line of code there.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the Basic [Ubuntu server package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153265/what-does-the-basic-ubuntu-server-package-contain-in-software-selection-during#271396) and SSH from that list you showed during the server setup. These are listed further down at the bottom.

If need be you can [install SSH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51925/how-do-i-configure-a-new-ubuntu-installation-to-accept-ssh-connections) later using

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ssh
```

As a matter a fact you can install other items later too as you most likely will have direct VPS access via your control panel. But it is better to do it right away. Faster that way.

With that setup you have a basic server setup and SSH.You should have a user you can use sudo commands with. Just ssh into the server

```
ssh user@vps.com
```

and do

```
sudo su
```

add you password and then run the suggested command by Forge as root:

```
wget -O forge.sh https://forge.laravel.com/servers/1008/vps?forge_token=Byix7lMfGiMTWh9KasdfjioafhewalkJeAHY; bash forge.sh
```

to download and execute the provisioning script.

Answer (score 0):

First of all ssh into your droplet. Run these commands.

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY
ssh forge@YOUR_DROPLET_IP
```

Then run the command as root (it will ask your root pass which you should have).